# React Context value not defined inside click handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have a functional component in which I am trying to use context, I get the value during import, but when I want to use it inside click handler, says its not defined

**component.js**

```
// I get these values over here
const [contextState, setContextState] = useContext(MyContext);
const clickHandler = (e) => {
    debugger; // when I am trying to log any of these values I get error of not defined
}

return (<button onClick={clickHandler}>Click me!</button>);
```

Moreover I have wrapped my **app.js** components as below

```
import { MyContextProvider } from './MyContext';
return (
    <Router>
        <MyContextProvider>
            <div className='App'>
                <Component />
            </div>
        </AuthContextProvider>
    </Router>
);
```

Now my context file, **myContext.js**

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react';

const MyContext = createContext([{}, () => {}]);

const MyContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [contextState, setContextState] = useState({
        userIsLoggedin: false,
        fName: '',
        lName: '',
        userName: ''
    });
    return (
        <myContext.Provider value={[contextState, setContextState]}>
            {props.children}
        </myContext.Provider>
    );
};

export { myContext, MyContextProvider };
```

Comment: Could you fix typos and provide full code of component.js?

Comment: Fixed all the typos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have debugged over and over again only to find out that it is not reading in debugger but value is getting printed in `console.log()` and while using it in code directly.

It appears there is some issue with chrome debugger in the current version.

So, anyone facing this issue please try using the variable or log it if on chrome

**update : it doesn't print in debugger, but it works with log. Probably it is expected, but it works**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some typos in your context file. First, use `MyContext` everywhere in that file (not `myContext`), and second, pay attention to the variable names you're specifying when you first call `useState` and then pass that same value to the context (`authState` vs `contextState`):

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";

const MyContext = createContext([{}, () => {}]);

const MyContextProvider = props => {
  const [authState, setAuthState] = useState({
    userIsLoggedin: false,
    fName: "",
    lName: "",
    userName: ""
  });
  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={[authState, setAuthState]}>
      {props.children}
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { MyContext as default, MyContextProvider };
```

[Here's a working codesandbox with your setup](https://codesandbox.io/s/ctx-rxcsz)

Comment: Well, those typos are unintentional (replacing original variable names). Fixed those anyway in the question, my problem is getting value when I use useContext(), not in the click handler

Comment: @AbhishekDhanrajShahdeo Could you include the full file for your functional component in your question as well? That'll make it easier to reproduce and address the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I think, You Need to Bind the event listener or use array func,

```
return (<button onClick={clickHandler.bind(this)}>Click me!</button>);
// Or,
return (<button onClick={ev => clickHandler(ev)}>Click me!</button>);
```

Comment: The component must be functional component because he is using `useContext` ==> no this at all. Additionally, `clickHandler` is an arrow function, you don't need to bind it.

Comment: This is a functional component, no use of this